# minio client (GO SDK) API calls are not working

Tags: go, amazon-s3, minio

None of the API calls to perform functions on the minio server running locally works

Here is how I am connecting to the server and listing the buckets

```
// Use a secure connection.
ssl := false

// Initialize minio client object.
minioClient, err := minio.New("localhost:9000", "minioadmin", "minioadmin", ssl)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

err = minioClient.MakeBucket("testlalabucket", "")
fmt.Println(err)
```

Throws error

```
[] XML syntax error on line 10: element <link> closed by </head>
```

Using the CLI to communicate with the minio server:

```
➜  ~ mc ls localminio
mc: <ERROR> Unable to list folder. XML syntax error on line 10: element <link> closed by </head>
```

Doing another operation (make buckets)

```
mc: <ERROR> Unable to make bucket `localminio/mylalabucket`. The specified bucket does not exist.
(1) mb-main.go:145 cmd.mainMakeBucket(..) Tags: [localminio/mylalabucket]
(0) client-s3.go:1120 cmd.(*s3Client).MakeBucket(..)
```

I can access the UI of the minio server to perform all these operation but just not able to do so via the API.

Answer (score 0):

Probably SDK version doesn't match the server version. Here is a complete example which works:

1. Start the server in docker

   ```
   docker run -p 9000:9000 minio/minio:RELEASE.2020-02-27T00-23-05Z server /data
   ```
2. Create `test.go` file as follows

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "log"

       "github.com/minio/minio-go/v6"
   )

   func main() {
       endpoint := "localhost:9000"
       accessKeyID := "minioadmin"
       secretAccessKey := "minioadmin"
       useSSL := false

       // Initialize minio client object.
       minioClient, err := minio.New(endpoint, accessKeyID, secretAccessKey, useSSL)
       if err != nil {
           log.Fatalln(err)
       }

       bucketName := "testlalabucket"
       err = minioClient.MakeBucket(bucketName, "")

       if err != nil {
           // Check to see if we already own this bucket (which happens if you run this twice)
           exists, errBucketExists := minioClient.BucketExists(bucketName)
           if errBucketExists == nil && exists {
               log.Printf("We already own %s\n", bucketName)
           } else {
               log.Fatalln(err)
           }
       }

       buckets, err := minioClient.ListBuckets()
       if err != nil {
           log.Fatalln(err)
       }

       for _, bucket := range buckets {
           log.Println(bucket)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run `GO111MODULE=on go run test.go`